# Sending multiple info to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqlcommand

I’m sorry about the nonsense question title, here is what i intended to asked:
in c#:
So i have a list that has integers(id’s),
and i have a query string:

```
myList //the list that has id’s in it.
string QueryString = “SELECT * FROM dbo.UserInfo WHERE id!= @idList”;
```

What im tryin to do is assign every item in the myList to the SqlCommand parameter:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(QueryString,con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(“@idList”,myList)
```

So in a nutshell, i want to choose all from `dbo.UserInfo` where id not equals to any item from myList.
Is there a way to do this or do i have to run the query for every item?

Comment: Pls pay attention to tagging! You are iusing ms sql server, not mysql!

Comment: Related - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: And stop cramming your code together. Readable code is less likely to be misunderstood  and is a good habit to develop.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need `left join` or `not exists`.  If `@idlist` is a string with comma separated values, then one method is:

```
select i.value as missing_id
from string_split(@idlist, ',') i left join
     dbo.UserInfo ui
     on ui.id = i.value
where ui.id is null;
```

Note that `string_split()` has been available since SQL Server 2016.  There are other (somewhat more cumbersome methods) in earlier versions of SQL Server.